# Webscraping using Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to webscrape the following website using R.

https://www.domain.com.au/suburb-profile/drummoyne-nsw-2047

I would like to pull the data in the table underneath the "Market Trends" heading

I've tried the following which does not work

```
    url <- "https://www.domain.com.au/suburb-profile/drummoyne-nsw-2047"

page <- read_html(url)

contentnodes <- page %>% 
  html_nodes("div.css-15dn4s") %>%
  html_attr("table") %>%
  jsonlite::fromJSON()
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at intermediate contents. If you just step through your pipe, you can notice when things go wrong.

```r
contentnodes <- page %>% 
  html_nodes("div.css-15dn4s")
contentnodes
# {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Let's find it a different way. To find html classes, we can use `.`-leading strings:

```r
page %>%
  html_nodes(".css-15dn4s8")
# {xml_nodeset (1)}
# [1] <table aria-describedby="market-data-context" class="css-15dn4s8">\n<thea ...
page %>%
  html_nodes(".css-15dn4s8") %>%
  html_table()
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 7 × 7
#   Bed@media (max-width:720px){.css…¹ Type  Media…² Avg d…³ Clear…⁴ Sold …⁵ ``   
#   <chr>                              <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <int> <chr>
# 1 .css-gsqvet{stroke-linejoin:round… House $1.685m 32 days 67%          17 .css…
# 2 3                                  House $2.242m 41 days 54%          28 Open 
# 3 4                                  House $3.4m   23 days 61%          23 Open 
# 4 5                                  House $3.745m 66 days 77%          15 Open 
# 5 1                                  Unit  $740k   -       -            11 Open 
# 6 2                                  Unit  $1.1m   46 days 74%          68 Open 
# 7 3                                  Unit  $1.825m 60 days 74%          27 Open 
# # … with abbreviated variable names
# #   ¹​`Bed@media (max-width:720px){.css-1lps80v{position:absolute !important;height:1px;width:1px;overflow:hidden;-webkit-clip:rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);clip:rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);-webkit-clip:rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);clip:rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);}}rooms`,
# #   ²​`Median price`, ³​`Avg days on market`, ⁴​`Clearance rate`,
# #   ⁵​`Sold this year`
```

This is a list with a table, we can extract it using `` `[[` ``:

```r
contentnodes <- page %>%
  html_nodes(".css-15dn4s8") %>%
  html_table()
contentnodes <- contentnodes[[1]]
as.data.frame(contentnodes)
# *** output flushed ***
contentnodes
# # A tibble: 7 × 7
#   Bed@media (max-width:720px){.css…¹ Type  Media…² Avg d…³ Clear…⁴ Sold …⁵ ``   
#   <chr>                              <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <int> <chr>
# 1 .css-gsqvet{stroke-linejoin:round… House $1.685m 32 days 67%          17 .css…
# 2 3                                  House $2.242m 41 days 54%          28 Open 
# 3 4                                  House $3.4m   23 days 61%          23 Open 
# 4 5                                  House $3.745m 66 days 77%          15 Open 
# 5 1                                  Unit  $740k   -       -            11 Open 
# 6 2                                  Unit  $1.1m   46 days 74%          68 Open 
# 7 3                                  Unit  $1.825m 60 days 74%          27 Open 
# # … with abbreviated variable names
# #   ¹​`Bed@media (max-width:720px){.css-1lps80v{position:absolute !important;height:1px;width:1px;overflow:hidden;-webkit-clip:rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);clip:rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);-webkit-clip:rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);clip:rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);}}rooms`,
# #   ²​`Median price`, ³​`Avg days on market`, ⁴​`Clearance rate`,
# #   ⁵​`Sold this year`
```

Comment: Wow this is perfect thank you. As a beginning this answer was super helpful to step through the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(rvest)
  library(dplyr)
})

url <- "https://www.domain.com.au/suburb-profile/drummoyne-nsw-2047"
page <- read_html(url)

contentnodes <- page %>%
  html_element("div.css-0") %>%
  html_table() %>%
  `[`(-1)

contentnodes
#> # A tibble: 7 × 6
#>   Type  `Median price` `Avg days on market` `Clearance rate` Sold this y…¹ ``   
#>   <chr> <chr>          <chr>                <chr>                    <int> <chr>
#> 1 House $1.685m        32 days              67%                         17 .css…
#> 2 House $2.242m        41 days              54%                         28 Open 
#> 3 House $3.4m          23 days              61%                         23 Open 
#> 4 House $3.745m        66 days              77%                         15 Open 
#> 5 Unit  $740k          -                    -                           11 Open 
#> 6 Unit  $1.1m          46 days              74%                         68 Open 
#> 7 Unit  $1.825m        60 days              74%                         27 Open 
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​`Sold this year`
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi @Rui Barradas, when I run this code it seems to take ages to run when I run the contentnodes part. Any idea why this might be? EDIT: Actually it is the page <- read_html(url) part

Comment: @MuzzMan123 That's a RStudio thing, when I run the code in RGui (I'm on Windows 11) or with the command line `Rscript so_q76032640.R` it reads the page very quickly.